# How to authenticate the same user on multiple clients using OAuth2?

Tags: oauth-2.0

I'm using the Resource Owner Password Credentials flow to authenticate my iOS app against an API that I provide. This is working fine, and I get the access token and can refresh tokens when they expire.

However if a user installs the app on multiple clients e.g. iPhone and iPad and authenticates with the same username and password they both get the same access token. The client that is first to refresh the access token works fine using the new access token, but the other client no longer works as it is using the previous access token.

The obvious solution is to allow a user (resource owner) to have multiple access tokens and return a new access token every time they authenticate. This then presents the problem of how should I clean up the old access tokens?

Or is there a better way of authenticating the same user on multiple clients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several strategies to handle tokens, I suggest using self-contained tokens. As far as I know most big OAuth2 providers use this solution. Self-contained tokens pack all significant token information with some security data, see e.g. [JSON Web Tokens](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-json-web-token-06) with [signature](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-jose-json-web-signature-11) or [encryption](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-jose-json-web-encryption-11). Self-contained tokens don't need to be stored in a database, expire over time but still can be safely validated. However, revoking such tokens is not trivial without a database.

Using self-contained tokens, each of your clients may have their own access token and you don't have to bother with cleaning up old tokens from your database.